# Filter is not returning a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I am working in React and using the filter array to compare the value of the returned array to the original array. However the filtered array is not returned. Here is the code I have:

```
const removeFromCart = id => {
const filteredCart = cart.filter(product => product.id !== id)
setCart(filteredCart)
```

If I use console.log on the cart variable set by setCart the new filtered array is shown. If I use console.log on filteredCart an empty array is shown. The filtered array also shows if !== is changed to ==.

When searching for a product by id to update a property an empty array is returned. Here is the code:

```
const addToCart = (id, name, price) => {
let inCart = cart.filter(product => product.id === id)
...
}
```

I know the filter function returns elements that pass the test so for the second code block, the object with the same id value should be returned instead of an empty array.

Comment: if both `===` and `!==` return an empty array, perhaps `cart` is an empty array to begin with - in fact, that's the only explanation

Comment: I doubt Javascript `Array.prototype.filter` is broken. How are you verifying/validating that your functions and logic aren't working as expected? Please show us in an update to your question.

Comment: @Andy I understand what you mean, but React state updater functions are completely synchronous. It's that in React enqueued state updates are *asynchronously* processed. It is clearer to think of `setCart` as a request to update state.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the ids in the object are integers you will need to coerce the string id you pass to the function to an integer.
2. If you want to log the state after it's been updated you'll need to use `useEffect` and pass in `cart` as a dependency because enqueued state functions are processed asynchronously.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example({ data }) {

  const [ cart, setCart ] = useState(data);

  function removeFromCart(e) {
    const { id } = e.target.dataset;
    const filteredCart = cart.filter(product => product.id !== +id);
    console.log(filteredCart)
    setCart(filteredCart);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(cart));
  }, [cart]);

  return (
    <div>
      {cart.map(obj => {
        return (
          <div>
            <div>{obj.name}
              &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <span
                className="remove"
                data-id={obj.id}
                onClick={removeFromCart}
              >[Remove]
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Cheese' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Bread' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Jam' }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={data} />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.remove { cursor: pointer; }
.remove:hover { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```